# Plotting categorial data as a lineplot in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to duplicate what a Seaborn countplot is able to do, but with a lineplot. Below is a code sample showing what countplot is doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03'],
    'type' : ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C']
    })

sns.countplot(
    data=df, x=df['date'], hue=df['type'])
plt.show()
```

which produces this graph:
[image: countplot graph]

I want to do the same thing, but with a line graph, so that x= date, y= amount of type for that date, and hue= type.

So my question is... Is this possible? I have tried with multiple different Seaborn graphs (relplot, lineplot, etc) and have not got this to work.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @FedericoBaù - only, it is not a picture of code/error.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do it by first get the size of each date and type with `groupby.size` and use `lineplot` with the transformed dataframe.

```
sns.lineplot(
    data=df.groupby(['date','type']).size().reset_index(name='count'), 
    x='date', y='count', hue='type')
```

Comment: This seems to have done it! Furthermore, by adding marker='o' to the Seaborn code, a dot is added to the graph for each date that a type occurs  (if marker isn't added and type is 0 then the line will just stop)